# "Field of study" vs. "subject of study"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

What is the difference between *field* and *subject* and what is the discipline here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- "*field of study*" refers a broad area of academic interest containing many topics, for example, "*human cell growth is my field of study.*"
- "*subject of study*" refers to a specific entity of interest within a given context, for example, "*The HeLa cell line has emerged as an important subject of study.*"

I should also point out that the term *subject of study* is significantly less common:
[image: ngram]